How to make buttons inside of a list tappable
I have this view that is a subview of a view that has a list in it:
struct MyView: View {

    @State private var selection: String?
    @State private var statusMessage = ""

    var body: some View {

        Section(header: Text("Selected Item - \(selection ?? "Not selected")")) {
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    SomeView(selectedLocation: $selection)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Choose item")
                        .foregroundStyle(.accent)

                })
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

                HStack {
                    firstButton
                    secondButton
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private extension MyView {

    var firstButton: some View {
        Button(action: firstAction) {
            Text("First Button")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
               
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            
        }
    }

    var secondButton: some View {
        Button(action: secondAction) {
            Text("Second Button")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
           
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                
        }
    }
}

Visually this looks like a a "table view row" that has "Choose Item" text with an chevron on top, and at the bottom there are two buttons.
What is happening is that when you tap on any of buttons, navigation link opens up the next screen (SomeView).
But what I want to achieve is that I have buttons tappable and to execute their actions.
What I tried is to set buttons style and also to do something like:
.contentShape(Rectangle())

But that didn't help in this case.
What's the best way to handle this? Am I missing something?
Additionally, what would be the best way to make the lower part of a 'row' where buttons are placed non-tappable, so that when the user taps between buttons, navigation is not triggered?
